# Query regarding the RSS Feeds - data load in my server

Tags: java, php, database, rss

I am grabbing the RSS feeds from various websites and displaying the content like Title, Title link, associated image and short description in my  site.

i am generating the RSS feeds with the same details like Title, Title link, associated image and short description in my site for the users to grab them.

Now, in my RSS feeds i am grabbing the image from the original source. not from my website. i am using the Feedburner to publish the feeds. Now my query, will my server bandwidth will reduced as i am taking the image from the original source or will it be the same as taking the image from my server.

i am using the FEEDBUNER to reduce the data load in my server especially images.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how you're "grabbing the image from the original source" or what image you're grabbing, but look at the stored data. if it's just a url or an img tag then no, if it's a large string then yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just including the original image URL in your feed, then you are not hosting the image to clients.  Therefore clients downloading the image are not using your server's bandwidth.  Moreover, if you are only sharing your FeedBurner feed with the world, then most of the requests to your server should only be from FeedBurner.  The approach you are using should help to minimize bandwidth used by your server.